# Can't manage to extract or convert SWF file because they seem to be corrupted

Tags: image, flash, swfobject

So I've extracted from a website a bunch of swf file which are photos.

What I was intending to do is converting them using swf tool.

However whatever I'm trying on thoose I'm ending up with :

> ./503141211.swf is not a valid SWF file or contains errors.

For exemple I've tried to render them with :

`swfrender 2773003.swf -o test.png`

Any idea why this is happening?

You can find one of the file there if you want :
[Link to file](http://www.abrazosentimental.com/communities/6/000/001/111/606/images/3503270035.swf)

Otherwise do you have a solution to extract an image from this link?

Comment: What's with the downvote? Guy was just asking if any Flash coders knew what's happening with this unusual SWF file...

Comment: @VC.One Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SWF files are already in JPEG format.

**Solution**: Try renaming them from `.swf` to `.jpg`.

**Extended version:**
If you ever suspect some file corruption, then first check the bytes with a hex-editor. Correct SWF beginning bytes are `43 57 53` (CWS) or sometimes begins with bytes `46 57 53` (FWS).

Your [linked SWF file](http://www.abrazosentimental.com/communities/6/000/001/111/606/images/3503270035.swf) begins with `FF D8 FF` which is usually expected in JPEG files.
Also seeing `JFIF` signature confirms that this is a JPEG image file (not a Flash SWF file).

[image]

So after renaming from `3503270035.swf` to `3503270035.jpg` we get this result in image viewer:

[image]

Comment: Holly hell, How could I knew that haha I've lost sooo much time. Thank you very much mate !